# Having trouble sending JavaMail over company domain

Tags: java, dns, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail to automate a process at work. I want to send the email with JavaMail with both emails ending with @business.com. Here's a snippet:

```
String host = "smtp.fakename.com";

    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);

    try {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("fakename@business.com"));
        msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("anotherfakename@business.com", "Name"));
        msg.setSubject("Test E-Mail through Java");

        Transport.send(msg);
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully...");
    }
```

I'm confused why it isn't working. I figured that I wouldn't need to do any sort of authentication because the email is sending over the same domain, but I have tried to use authentication also. I have tried going through ports 25, 110, 143, 465, and 587. I was able to use this same code with the addition of password authentication to send an email over gmail. The most common error I see is "could not connect to SMTP host: ...". Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to telnet to your SMTP server - is it accessible?

Comment: I'm installing telnet now

Comment: it reached the SMTP server through port 25

Answer (score 2):

```
String host = "smtp.xyz.com";
final String username = "xyz@business.com";
final String password = "your password";

Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
// go to account setting -> smtp setting and get server name and port
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "your server name");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "your server port");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");

try {
    Session session = Session.getInstance(prop,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xyz@business.com"));

    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("abc@business.com"));
    msg.setSubject("Test E-Mail through Java");

    Transport.send(msg,username,password);
    System.out.println("Sent message successfully...");
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

you can try this may it helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    String host = "smtp.fakename.com";

    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    // go to account setting -> smtp setting and get server name and port
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "server name");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "port");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");

    try {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("fakename@business.com"));

        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("anotherfakename@business.com"));
        msg.setSubject("Test E-Mail through Java");

        Transport.send(msg);
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully...");
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Whether you need to authenticate, and which host and port to connect to, depends on the configuration of your internal mail server.  You should ask your system administrator for the configuration information necessary to configure a mail client to connect to your mail server.